# Understanding modbus tcp output (reading temperature from thermocouple)

Tags: python, tcp, modbus, temperature, modbus-tcp

Upon reading an input register, I get the following output:

```
0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x5 0x1 0x4 0x2 0x4 0xf3
```

I'm trying to convert the data portion (0x4 0xf3) into a recognizable temperature. Any help? I'm using a T type thermocouple. I have approximations of what the temperatures should be at each point.

Other data points:

```
0x4 0xf3 (~ 116 degrees C)
0x6 0x3A (~ 158 degrees C)
0xfd 0x55 (~ -55 degrees C)
0xfb 0x7b (~ -107.9 degrees C)
```

Comment: if you already know the byte positions of the value, you can calculate thr value by taking into account resolution, offset and scale. If the sensor has 0.25 deg C resolution, divide the word by 4 for example. Read the datasheet to find the needed values.

Comment: I guess I'm not completely sure what I'm reading from my device. For example, 0x6 0x3A (digital: 1594) for ~ 158 degrees and 0xfd 0x55 (digital: 64853) for ~55 degrees. My device automatically computes the temperatures from the thermocouple and displays it in their own software, which is where I am getting the reference temperatures from. I'm not sure if what I'm getting over modbus is a voltage reading or temperature

Comment: Nevermind I think I figured it out